# css having a full height div next to a fixed height one?

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve a very simple thing: having 2 divs in an absolute positioned outer div.

Inner divs are `header` and `content`.

`Header` has a fixed height (but it depends on the font size, i.e. it does not have any height attribute preset).

The goal is to set the `content` to be under the `header` and force it to take all the space downwards without making the page any higher than the viewport.

<s>Please don't recommend flex properties, as I found it to be not quite browser-independent. Worked well in Firefox but in Chrome it ruined the page.</s>

Here is the JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/danergo/qpjc3mr0/7/

### Update

JSFiddle updated. What ruined flexbox is having another item in the content which wants tp use 100% height of the content.

Wha

Comment: *Please don't recommend flex properties, as I found it to be not quite browser-independent.* Then you've done it wrong.

Comment: connexo: how can I make it work with a child inside the flexbox? Please see my update

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, preferably as a [mcve]. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by not having us go off site to provide critical information. Fiddles/Codepen etc are OK to provide supplemental information, but all critical info should be here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Why not use CSS grid? Support in browsers is good enough to make it the way to go: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: your issue is the use of height:100% on the table element. Remove it and do the same like you did with flexbox on the upper level

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to achieve what you need is using a CSS grid. For it to work in IE 11 as well, you'd need to add some proprietary CSS rules. If you're interested in those, I can add them as well.

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "content";
  height: 100vh;
  background:red;
}

#header {
  grid-area: header;
  background:yellow;
}

#content {
  background:gray;
  grid-area: "content";
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    content
  </div>


</div>
```

The key part of the code is

```
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
```

which means the grid consists of two rows, the first of which is sized `auto`, meaning it will adjust to whatever is inside. The second one is declared `1fr` which tells it to cover the rest.

Should you run into the problem of the `#content` element becoming too high, replace `1fr` with `minmax(0, 1fr)`.

Comment: "For it to work in IE 11 as well, you'd need to add some proprietary CSS rules. If you're interested in those, I can add them as well." Could you please do it?

Answer (score -1):

You may be achieve this by setting height on page load by using jQuery. Please see code snippet below

```js
var headerHeight = $("#header").outerHeight();
$("#content").css( { height: 'calc(100% - ' + headerHeight + 'px)' } );
```

```css
#main {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}

#header {
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
}

#content {
  /* background:gray; */
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">

<div id="header">
Header
</div>
<div id="content">
content
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: That is totally unnecessary. It's really bad practice to solve problems with Javascript, and worse doing it with jQuery, if a CSS solution is available.